# JSON Api Call with "POST"

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, wordpress, api

I try the following test-code to register a user at my Wordpress system (JSON Api User plugin is installed):

```
<form id="register" name="register" method="post">
<input id="submitLogin" type="submit" value="Abschicken" onclick="register()">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


function register() {
 $.ajax({
url: 'http://XXX.de/api/user/register/?username=xxx@test.de&email=xxx@test.de&nonce=d60besdfee&display_name=xxx@test.de&user_pass=rtzrtzrtz0&apikey=gfhrtzh465&callback=?',
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){

 }
 });
}

</script>
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the endpoint you're calling uses [**JSONP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), not just JSON. JSONP is a data format (JSON) *and* transmission mechanism (script element). It's inherently only GET, not POST, because under the covers what it really is is adding a script element to the page with a `src` attribute, which makes the browser get the script.

If the endpoint supports [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), you can use POST (you'll want to remove the `callback=?` part of the URL). If it doesn't, you cannot use POST to talk to that endpoint cross-origin because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Side note: I can't see any reason your call *needs* to use POST, as you're not sending any data (no `data` property in the options for the `ajax` call). You may simply want to remove the `type: "POST"`, change `dataType: "json"` to `dataType: "jsonp"`, and remove the `&callback=?` (because jQuery will handle that when you specify `dataType: "jsonp"`).